# String replace(), return value comparison using '=='

Tags: java, return-value, equals-operator

`System.out.print("a".replace('a','1')=="a".replace('a','1'));`

`true` was expected as replace() returns String and String comparison is possible with `==`.
But the above code prints `false`. Explanations?

Comment: You shouldn't compare strings in java with `==`. It checks if their references are the same, not their values.

Comment: I understood the concept of **String Interning** via the above post by Sir Nizet. That's the reason for `S.O.Pln ("a"=="a");` returning `true`. Thank you all for your time and co-operation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` checks if they are the same object in memory, so at the same location.

Since these are two distinct strings that just happen to have the same content you need to compare with `.equals` which compares values not reference.

Comment: Or if you want to compare the number values you are replacing them with, you need to parseInt that new replacement and THEN you can use `==`

Comment: Sir Jean:S.O.Pln ("ab"=="ab"); returns `true`. Do they share same memory?

Comment: @ChaZ In this case yes because they are known at compile time so they are given a static location in memory and not created at run-time. It's a tricky case. To be safe, always compare strings with .equals unless you specifically know you care about memory location.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin:Will do. Btw, it's just an academic question. I very well knew the use of `equals()` but now, well understand the risks of `==` too. Well appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, string comparison is not advisable with ==. In certain cases e.g.:

```
new String("test") == new String("test")
```

it returns false.

All this is because theoretically Java should search for certain string in string pool, but in practice there are operations that returns new object instead of the one that resides in string pool.

This is very important to always use "equals" method instead of ==!!

Comment: I would go so far as to say in *most* cases the equality test will return false.

Comment: I would go so far as to say never use `==` to compare strings.

Comment: Agreed. Was an academic question, that's the reason I asked.
Btw why `S.O.Pln ("ab"=="ab");` returns `true`? They don't share same memory I suppose.

Comment: They do, read about string pool.

Comment: @MichalBorek:Thanks got the idea. For fairly utilizing the memory and proper storage of duplicate Strings. :)

Comment: This knowledge is reeeaally important. You may have memory problems if some stupid method creates a lot of same String objects in memory. You can then use "intern()" method to force JVM putting it in string pool to free memory. Study this topic because from my experience it may help you find some performance problems in future :)

Comment: @MichalBorek:Sure Sir Borek, I hope this will help me in my project. Great pleasure to receive a help from ur side. :)